# How to access and change a Tilemap's Order in Layer?

Tags: unity, tilemap

I'm making a game about two ghosts, and an important thing that I want to add is the possibility to pass through walls. I have managed to make the passable behaviour and everything.

Next, I need to change the Tilemap's Order in Layer number. That's because I want to add some things inside the Tilemap that should be shown until player passes the wall. The way I though of to do this is to decrease the tilemap's layer order when the player is inside it, and put it back to the previous value when player exits.

Comment: Have you tried [Renderer.sortingOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.htm) ?

Comment: Yes i found it already. Thanks, my problem is solved

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your problem! Want to write up your solution as an Answer below that you can mark as Accepted? This can help future users, and also earn you some reputation from folks who find your answer useful.

Comment: Please post that as an Answer below, not as a comment.

Comment: yeah hah i'm new using StackOverFlow sorry

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with `GetComponent<TilemapRenderer>().sortingOrder = x;`

Comment: This answer would benefit from showing more code...

Comment: There is a way to do that like  the classic rectangle only for code? i don't know the name of that feature, but i hope you understand

Comment: Yes, you write the code and you hit "code sample" in the top edit bar. If you have trouble, someone else will fix the formatting. The idea here is that you show us a bit more how and where you use the line you posted. Please use the edit feature below the Answer text.